# Unable to run application with Twitter4j from command line

Tags: java, command-line, classpath, twitter4j

I have included the Twitter4j .jar files in my classpath like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path=""/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/twitter4j-3.0.5/lib/twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/twitter4j-3.0.5/lib/twitter4j-stream-3.0.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path=""/>
</classpath>
```

My application runs fine through my IDE, but when I attempt to run it through the command complaining about not being able to find the `StatusListener` class which should be inside of the `twitter4j-stream-3.0.5.jar`:

```
>java MyTwitterApp
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j/StatusListener
```

Is there anything else that I need to do in order to run an application with twitter4j from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Specifically, the part that says:

> The default class path is the current directory. Setting the CLASSPATH
>   variable or using the -classpath command-line option overrides that
>   default, so if you want to include the current directory in the search
>   path, you must include "." in the new settings.

Seems I overlooked this when setting my `CLASSPATH` Windows Environment Variable. I added the `.` to my classpath like so:

```
.;C:/twitter4j-3.0.5/lib/twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar;C:/twitter4j-3.0.5/lib/twitter4j-stream-3.0.5.jar
```

Using a wildcard to simplify this further, it becomes:

```
.;C:/twitter4j-3.0.5/lib/*
```

which allows me to use the `java MyTwitterApp` syntax correctly. It looks for the associated `.jar` files that I am using for my project and the `.` allows me to use the current directory as my classpath for all other Java applications, thus not breaking any compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar` and `twitter4j-stream-3.0.5.jar` in your command line shell classpath.

**EDIT**

In Windows

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;<Path to>/twitter4j-stream-3.0.5.jar;<Path to>/twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar;<Path to Directory containing Class files or Start of Package>
```

In Unix/Mac

```
set CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:<Path to>/twitter4j-stream-3.0.5.jar:<Path to>/twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar:<Path to Directory containing Class files or Start of Package>
```

Before executing

```
java MyTwitterApp
```

Comment: Setting the CLASSPATH seems to have resolved the issue of finding the jar files, but now I am getting an `Error: Could not find or load main class MyTwitterApp` when trying to run it from the command line. If I delete the CLASSPATH, I am able to run other projects from the command line. As soon as the CLASSPATH is added, I lose this ability.

Comment: Is your MyTwitterApp.class is in a package or it has no package?

Comment: It is not in a package. MyTwitterApp.java is in the default package.

Comment: Then you need to add the Path which leads to the directory where you have MyTwitterApp.class file. Please see my edit in classpath

Comment: This works, but it is not ideal. I would have to add every single path to every single one of my Java applications this way. Is there a better solution?